# Libraries act differently depending on if they are installed or not

Tags: python

I have a Python library I wrote which has been acting up on me. I have a set of variables which change the way the library works. In testing it all worked fine, but when I `python lib.py install` the variables have no effect on the library. I broke this down to the simplest example possible:

Library:

```
    ##lib.py
    config="Original"

    def run():
        print config
```

Script:

```
    import lib

    lib.config="New"
    lib.run()
    print lib.config
```

If you place the library in the same directory as the script and run it the output is:

```
    New
    New
```

But if you install the library and then try the script using the library from the dist-packages the output is:

```
    Original
    New
```

Could someone explain what is going on? I'm a bit confused and terribly interested in the happenings and reason. Additionally am I doing programatical configuration totally wrong?

**Edit**

It turns out the problem is the **init**.py file. It's basically like importing a library that just imports another library. When you import an installed module it looks at the folder `lib` and the file **init**.py. **init**.py is just a one liner `from lib import *`. It simply pretends to be the actual library, but that causes an odd problem if you use a global variable. A simulated example of what is essentially going on:

```
##init.py
from lib import *
```

Script:

```
import init

init.config = 'New'
init.run()
print init.config
```

Output:

```
Original
New
```

The function run() looks for `config` in lib.py, but `print init.config` looks for it in init.py. Thanks for the help everyone. Fix is to change the way the module installs (no **init**.py). Eventually, I hope to remove all the global variables, but for the time being everything works perfect.

Comment: Configuration should generally be per-object-instance and not static (global), unless there is a *really* good reason for doing it statically.  And even then, object instances should support overriding any sort of global configuration.

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce this behavior on Python 2.6.6.

Comment: @trydyingtolive What you are describing does not seem plausible.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe would be inconsistent with how Python works (read, if you like, "I don't believe you did precisely that and got precisely that result").

If you go importing `lib` from different places or in different ways, though, you could be ending up with two copies of it, either two copies of one of the modules or one of the current-directory `lib` and the other the installed `lib`. If you *are* getting this "Original"/"New" behaviour, that seems to me the most likely reason.

Comment: I too thought that might be the reason. So I didn't name the two libraries the same. I also agree with you that isn't how Python works, which is why this is surprising to me.

Comment: @trydyingtolive: then, to try to pinpoint it, `print lib` in the places where you are using it and compare the paths; if they're the same, start comparing the module object identities. Looking through `sys.modules` can also help.

Comment: The big difference I see is that when you run it from the same directory it is run as lib.pyc and when you run it from installed you run it from __init__.pyc. Which all __init__ does is import *.

Comment: __init__ is the problem. If I create a new file named init.py which imports * from lib.py and import init it has the same problem.

Comment: @trydyingtolive: " If I create a new file named init.py which imports"??? What are you talking about?  Please **update** the question to be very, very accurate and complete about **every file** in your current directory.  Details matter.  Accuracy matters.

Comment: @S.Lott init.py imports all of lib.py. Literally the whole file is `from lib import *`. This is to emulate the __init__.py file that is used in installed modules.

Comment: @trydyingtolive: Please **update** the question to include all the facts.  Please don't add facts as a comment to an answer.  Please **update** the question to include **all** the information.